# How to validate a login using a manually added field in a django admin users table

Tags: python-3.x, django

I want to link my login page to my django admin users table. So that users of the page can only access the check in page if their ID and pin is saved in the django admin field. The field already has manually added values and I want to connect these values to a login form. Please I am new to Django

## Create your views here.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':


from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect




@csrf_protect
def checkit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        r_number = request.POST.get("room")
        a_paid = request.POST.get("amount")
        o_name = request.POST.get("occuname")
        o_email = request.POST.get("occumail")
        o_occupation = request.POST.get("occu")
        n_of_n = request.POST.get("night")
        s_date = request.POST.get("start")
        e_date = request.POST.get("end")
        new_data = chech_in(room_number=r_number, amount_paid=a_paid, occupant_name=o_name,
                        occupant_email=o_email, occupant_occupation=o_occupation,
                        number_of_nights=n_of_n, start_date=s_date, end_date=e_date
                        )
        new_data.save()
        return redirect('check:checkit')
    return render(request, 'check/checkin.html')
```

Comment: please clearify your question. I didn't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are trying to want . The login page is the template which authenticates the user . Whereas the data about the user is always stored in the user_authuser table .